# Clone using http and git protocol

Tags: git

I'm using windows git bash to work with GIT.

I was using two commands to clone a project; first using the `git://` URL:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle.git
```

That command fail with this error:

```
Cloning into 'winsparkle'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=No such file or directory
```

But this version of the command works fine:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle.git
```

I see only one difference in these commands and I suppose this is protocol - `http` and `git`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, why one protocol works fine while other fails for the same project?

Comment: This has to be a temporary connectivity issue, because I can clone it with `git clone git://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle.git` just fine. If you try again it will probably work.

Comment: Smells like firewall misconfiguration; check that the default git port is allowed through everywhere on the network path.

Comment: maybe your firewall blocks ssh connection port?